# How to Search Users from Reading Excel file that contain First and Last Name

Tags: excel, search, vbscript, active-directory

I want to update all User information as per given in Excel file and excel file contain more that 500 user information

I am trying to write down the script that Read Excel File , get a data for Searching and than find the object in Active Directory. For Eg.

Suppose I have Excel File Name as `All_Users_List.xls`

And that file there are information about all users information and there title and manger information

```
FirstName  LastName  title  EmailAddress  Phone  ManageFirstName  ManagerLastName
```

VBScript open a file and read a data from each row and Search for user Who's First Name and Last name Match then bind it to modify and update the information given in Excel file. If it find more than one user it should show all users who's First and last Name are same with additional information like Description and ask for input and if no user and manager found in Active Directory it should mark the Row with Red color for manually work latter for searching or identifing which user is not update as per the excel file.

Comment: That is a very big ask. How far have you got? What references have you found for working eith Active Directory in VBScript? Have you looked the numerous posts here on working with Excel and ADO?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have Excel installed on the machine where this is running you can get out the information from the Excel file using automation. See this article for further information on how to do this: [How to automate Excel from a client-side VBScript](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/198703)

To read/write the value from a cell, use something like `wb.Activesheet.Range("A1").Value`.

This old SO question should give you a starting point for the AD stuff: [Querying Active Directory using VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090336/querying-active-directory-using-vbscript)

Please note, automating Excel is not supported on a server, so this solution is probably only suitable if you're going to run this code on a client machine rather than some kind of server. Otherwise you should probably look at ADO rather than Automation (this might also be better if you have a lot of date since it can be a little slow to read/write a lot of records via automation).