# search by samaccountname with wildcards

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have this code:

```
 public static DataTable ExecutesAMAccountNameQuery(string sAMAccountName)
        {
            string filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" + sAMAccountName + "))";
            return ExecuteADQuery("GC:", filter);
        }
```

It only works with the full username, I dont know the syntax to make it work with wildcards, like a LIKE in sql?

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you're using .NET 3.5 or newer, you can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a UserPrincipal 
UserPrincipal qbeUser = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
qbeUser.SamAccountName = "Esteban*";

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

// find all matches
foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
{
    // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal" - it could be user, group, computer.....          
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`. Or see the [MSDN documentation on the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace.

Of course, depending on your need, you might want to specify other properties on that "query-by-example" user principal you create:

- `DisplayName` (typically: first name + space + last name)
- `SAM Account Name` - your Windows/AD account name
- `User Principal Name` - your "username@yourcompany.com" style name

You can specify any of the properties on the `UserPrincipal` and use those as "query-by-example" for your `PrincipalSearcher`.

Comment: I am only maintaining some existing code, so I dont want to mess up a lot with the code you sent me, however with this I suppose I can put * at the beginning and end and it should work also.

Comment: like this: sAMAccountName=*" + sAMAccountName + "*)

Comment: @EstebanV.: [according to this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198823.aspx) it seems it should work, yes.

Comment: This answer shows .vbs script doing wildcard query by sAMAccountName. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17025882/185565

Comment: is this case sensitive?

Comment: @DeniseMichelledelBando: No, I believe these attributes are all searched in a **non-case-sensitive** fashion

Comment: [MSDN Documentation of Query by Example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384378(v=vs.90).aspx) is worth referencing