# DirectorySearcher User search filter is invalid

Tags: active-directory, ldap

> The (&(objectClass=user)(|(&(SAMAccountName=jdoe*))) search filter is
>   invalid.

I'm trying to locate John Doe's user account by his username, jdoe. I've used a number of variants of this search string, and they all return this error. What am I doing wrong? I'm building it out like this:

```
var deSearch = new DirectorySearcher(de);
deSearch.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(|(&(SAMAccountName={0}*)))", uname);
SearchResult result = deSearch.FindOne();
```

Comment: FYI, searches with `*` don't work with sAMAccountName or distinguishedName.

Comment: This isn't correct. They work if parentheses match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using .Net 3.5 or later, you can use a UserPrincipal object to get user information, like this.

```
PrincipalContext pcontext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName);
UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pcontext,IdentityType.SamAccountName, "UserName");
```

Comment: This appears ideal, as it seems I can call GetUnderlyingObject when I need the DirectoryEntry.

Comment: I'm not sure if this works with wildcards, but if not, someone describes how to do that in another answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635124/search-by-samaccountname-with-wildcards).

Comment: I think you should avoid searching with Principals. They are basically a wrapper around DirectorySearcher, and thus, are slower. They are made for making the search easier to do, but it is slow.

Answer (score 6):

You need to close the opening parenthesis :

```
(&(objectClass=user)(|(&(SAMAccountName=jdoe*))))
```