# VBscript search sAMAccountName from CN

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, active-directory

I've written this script which pulls the sAMAccountName of the specified user from the AD via VBscript, but it seems to only work within my own OU group. Is this due to a permissions restriction within my company? Or is this due to something i'm not seeing in the code?

> ```
>  Dim result
> result = getsAMAccountName("Some Name")
> msgbox result
> ```

```
Function getsAMAccountName(name)
Dim adoCommand, adoConnection, strBase, strFilter, strAttributes
Dim objRootDSE, strDNSDomain, strQuery, adoRecordset, strsAM, objUser

Set adoCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
Set adoConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
adoConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
adoConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
Set adoCommand.ActiveConnection = adoConnection

Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")
strDNSDomain = objRootDSE.Get("defaultNamingContext")
msgbox strDNSDomain
strBase = "<LDAP://" & strDNSDomain & ">"

'be sure passed var usersel is referenced properly
strFilter = "(cn=" & name & ")"
strAttributes = "distinguishedName"

strQuery = strBase & ";" & strFilter & ";" & strAttributes & ";subtree"
adoCommand.CommandText = strQuery
adoCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 100
adoCommand.Properties("Timeout") = 30
adoCommand.Properties("Cache Results") = False

Set adoRecordset = adoCommand.Execute

Do Until adoRecordset.EOF

    strsAM = adoRecordset.Fields("distinguishedName").Value
    Set objUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & strsAM)
    getsAMAccountName = objUser.sAMAccountName
    adoRecordset.MoveNext
Loop

adoRecordset.Close
adoConnection.Close
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being permissions, be sure to include/specify a processID and PW when moving LDAP pulls to asp classic... and avoid asp classic

```
Set adoConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")                
            adoConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
                With adoConnection
                    .Properties("User ID") = ' Process ID goes
                    .Properties("Password") = 'password
                    .Properties("encrypt password") = True
                End With

        adoConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
        Set adoCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
        Set adoCommand.ActiveConnection = adoConnection
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it work when you specify the OU in your GetObject call?

```
GetObject("LDAP://OU=YourOU,DC=YourDomain,DC=com")
```

From this question [Querying Active Directory using VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090336/querying-active-directory-using-vbscript)

Comment: Looks like when i change the `Set objRootDSE = GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE")` to my specific OU it errors out on the next line, `strDNSdomain`

Comment: Its these same few lines of code that produce errors on the asp-classic page aswell, "activex element could not be created"