# vbs ldap query issues

Tags: vbscript, ldap, ldap-query

i am currently trying to use my small knowledge of scripting to search through ldap find a user based on a variable then get my the displayname for that user.
so far i ahve the below and im stuck

```
On Error Resume Next

Dim objNetwork 
Dim userName   

  Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network") 
  userName = objNetwork.UserName   
  WScript.Echo userName 


  Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
 Set objCommand =   CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
 objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
 objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"
 Set objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection

     objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 1000

        objCommand.CommandText =  _
  "<LDAP://dc=domain,dc=com>;(objectCategory=User);Name;Subtree"  
Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute

 objRecordSet.MoveFirst

  Do Until objRecordSet.Fields("Name").Value = username

  objRecordSet.MoveNext
  Loop

  Wscript.Echo objRecordSet.Fields("Name").Value
```

=  PLEASE HELP!!

I scartached the above and am now trying this but get syntax errors

```
option explicit dim cmd, cn, rs, objRoot,
set cmd = createobject("ADODB.Command") 
    set cn = createobject("ADODB.Connection") 

set rs = createobject("ADODB.Recordset") 
cn.open "Provider=ADsDSOObject;" 

cmd.activeconnection = cn set 

objRoot = getobject("LDAP://RootDSE") cmd.commandtext = "<LDAP://dn=domain,dn=com">;(&(objectClass=user)(!(objectClass=computer)            (sAMAccountName=first.last))));name,displayname;subtree"

cmd.properties("page size")=1000 set rs = cmd.execute 

wscript.echo rs("name")
```

Comment: This answer has .vbs example script doing search by SAMAccountName wildcard. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17025882/185565

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the attribute name is Name, and try displayName instead in this line:

```
"<LDAP://dc=domain,dc=com>;(objectCategory=User);Name;Subtree"
```

Comment: instead of going throught he entire directory how would i pass the username variable into the ldap search and then just have it echo the display name

im not good with vbs as well as i am with cmd heres what works in cmd for me


For /F  %a In ('Dsquery.exe * -filter "(&(objectClass=user)(!(objectClass=computer)(sAMAccountName=adam.sallee)))" ^|Dsget user -displayname ^|Find "Adam.Sallee"') Do Set display=%a

Comment: @TLDAN Consider changing the filter then to (&(objectCategory=User)(samAccountName=YOURVARIABLE)) in whatever format your language supports for variables.

Comment: `(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)...)` might be a better filter. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa746407(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Ya, it would be, but I did not wish to change much of his filter.

Comment: maybe starting over would be best.  what i want is to take the acccount name as a variable which i can get and then search the ldap with that account name and bring up the displayname field.

Comment: i added what i am trying now to my post

Answer (score 1):

ended up getting with this

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

```
Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")  

objConnection.Open "Provider=ADsDSOObject;" 
objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection  

strDomainName = "dc=domain,dc=com" 
strUserCN = username 
objCommand.CommandText = "<LDAP://" & strDomainName & ">;(&(objectCategory=person)     (objectClass=user)(cn=" & strUserCN & "));displayName;subtree"  

Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute  

If Not objRecordset.EOF Then  

strray = split(objRecordSet.Fields("displayName"),"(") 
strdat = strray(0)



username = trim(strdat)

End If
```