# Connecting to Active Directory from MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I am currently trying to pull User info from Active directory into MS Access Table. I am a bit confused if this is done by SQL query or VBA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL is used for working with relational databases and Access lets you run SQL against both itself and any ODBC relational data source.

Active Directory is also a database, but it is not a relational database (i.e. one that uses tables), instead it's a form of *graph-database* known as a hierarchical-database, with multiple root nodes. Each node has a set of properties, an ACL, and multiple child nodes. Nodes can be Containers, Users, Computers, Organizational Units, and so on.

To query Active Directory you use LDAP queries (as Active Directory is an implementation of LDAP).

VBA in Access is compatible with VBScript that uses LDAP, so you use techniques like these: [Querying Active Directory using VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090336/querying-active-directory-using-vbscript)

Confusingly, ADODB (Microsoft's COM-based database API) can be used to target both relational and non-relational databases. Note that in this example (from the above-linked question and answer) the `ADODB.Connection` is to `LDAP://RootDSE` instead of an Access or SQL Database, but the other concepts (Connections, Commands, and Parameters) are the same.

Comment: How do I first know I have a connection to AD from VBA and where are the result produced?

Comment: @wisenhiemer If you don't have a connection the code will fail by raising an error, and you get the results in an `ADODB.RecordSet` object retrieved from `ADODB.Command::Execute`.